# Convert mm to pixels

Tags: android

Does anyone have a good algorithm to convert mm to pixels on Android?

The thing is, I want to be able to set a minimum height of a View using mm as unit.

And no, I don't want to use android:minHeight in xml, this should be in the code.

Comment: If you're looking to do a one-off conversion (for instance for exporting sprites from Photoshop or designing your layout for a physical dimension), [here's a nifty converter](http://pixplicity.com/dp-px-converter/).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Convert 1mm to pixel

```
float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_MM, 1, 
                getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```