# Android Convert Pixels to inchec, millimeter

Tags: android, pixel, dpi, ppi

I want to accurately convert pixels to inches and mm.
I had tried to use all the properties of `displayMetrics` but was unsuccessful in getting the exact physical units in mobile.
I also tried to use `TypedValue.applyDimension` but as the documentation is not much explanatory still was unlucky.

This is the code I tried with displayMetrics

```
displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
```

when I try to get Pixels Per Inch by using
`displayMetrics.ydpi` or `displayMetrics.xdpi`, I am not getting the exact values as I am checking it by drawing a line of that much length on canvas and checked with actual ruler.

Comment: Did you try this one? http://stackoverflow.com/a/8657132/1438733

Comment: @Eric thanks for response..and Yes i did tried that code with IN, MM, DIP etc.. but no luck

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
DisplayMetrics mDisplayMetric = this.getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
float anyPixel = View.getMeasuredWidth(); //you can get Pixel from anywhere, it is a example from view
float widthInches =  TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_IN, size.x, mDisplayMetric);
```

Comment: where did you use the anyPixel?