# Translate Android movement to pixels

Tags: android

I would like to create Android app for viewing images.

The idea is that users keep their tablet flat on the table (for sake of simplicity, only X and Y for now) and to scroll the picture (one that is too big to fit the screen) by moving their tablets (yes, this app has to use tablet movement, sorry, no fingers allowed :) ).

I managed to get some basic framework implemented (implementing sensor listeners is easy), but I'm not sure how to translate "LINEAR_ACCELERATION" to pixels. I'm pretty sure it can be done (for example, check "photo sphere" or "panorama" apps that move content exactly as you move your phone) but I can't find any working prototype online.

Where can I see how that kind of "magic" is done in real world?

Comment: I suggest that you do some research on the mathematics used in graphics. Most of what you will find will be related to game programming, but the same principles apply here.

Comment: I think the easiest would be to use the `LINEAR_ACCELERATION` to get a real world unit (like mm) and then convert that to pixels. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656968/convert-mm-to-pixels) post that could help you.